# Get Android application from application context

Tags: android, android-context

I have access to application context but not to application. I want to get the application (so I can get all running activities), but couldn't find a way to do so. Is there an existing API to get application from application context or I will have to override getApplicationContext for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no such API out of the box. However, you can either get application context and cast it to Application object, or Extend Application class, and make it a singleton so you can grab an instance of it from everywhere.

```
 public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication singleton;

    // Returns the application instance 
    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        return singleton;
    }

        public final void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate(); 
            singleton = this;
        } 
    }
```